# Evaluating causal impact of a treatment at various time units

Tags: mixed-model, causality, causalimpact

I am trying to understand the causal impact of a treatment (T) that can be offered to people at different (and multiple) days until a desired outcome is reached. (for ex: a customer may be offered a treatment at day 0 from when they become a customer, and then at day 1, 5, 8 etc..). If the desired outcome is not reached after a limit of 30 days let's say, then no more treatments are offered.

I need to build an inferential model to estimate the impact of treatment T on the desired outcome at each day if it is offered, ie. what is the impact when offered at day 0 vs. day 1, 2, ... vs. day 30.

I am thinking of building a hierarchical linear model, where the 'day number' can be the grouping factor and the model includes a random slope for the treatment variable T (binary) for each day. Would this be a reasonable approach? Would also love to know if there other methods that may work better here.